# How can I get the public elements from a Rust module?

Tags: module, rust

In Node.js, I could get an array of the objects in `foo` with

```
Object.keys(require("foo"));
```

Is there any way I could do the same thing in Rust?

```
mod foo;
getobjs(foo);
```

Comment: This question strongly feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/281829). You may wish to consider asking a new question concerning what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this. This level of introspection of compile-time information simply doesn't exist at runtime. The concept of a *module* doesn't even exist.

If you are interested in compile-time information, you can do such things as build and view the docs (`cargo doc --open`) to see all the public items of the entire crate. You can probably also view the crate's documentation online before you use it.

There are also tools like the [Rust Language Server](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rls) which provide this type of information (and more) to editors and IDEs.